# using the params arg in emayili::render()

Tags: r, r-markdown, html-email

I'm trying to write a code that automates emailing (with `emayili`) R markdown reports with filtered data. Each user (email) should get his\her own unique filtered data fed into the email report.

My solution was to define a filter based on an R markdown parameter, and then (for) loop over the `params` arg in the `render()` function, outside the .Rmd file in a separate .R script. That way each user would get a unique markdown report with his\her filtered data. However that was not possible, since the `params` arg is not specified in the `emayili::render` wrapper function.

Is there a workaround? Perhaps I could render outside `emayili::envelope()`, using `rmarkdown::render()`, and then feed the outputted html(s) files into the `emayili::html()` function?
I couldn't make that work either.

Thanks,
Yoav

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the `emayili` package, and I'm somewhat surprised that it doesn't offer parameter setting, since that would be a prime use case. The doc do seem to suggest that it currently isn't featured, so you might want to raise a feature request with the author. (Update: as per the comment below, this feature has been added, [see here for details](https://github.com/datawookie/emayili/issues/79))

In the meantime, there are a couple of options:

**Use the environment to set variables**

You can design the .rmd file such that it picks up global variables from your emayili code:

```
username = 'Jabberwocky'
msg <- envelope() %>% render('template.Rmd') #.rmd picks up username and filters accordingly
```

Use this solution with caution, relying on global variables tends to be a headache.

**Manually manipulate .rmd file using string replacements**

Create an rmd file of the form

```
---
title: 'Email title'
#... your other stuff...
params:
   username: $USERNAME$
---
```

and in the program perform a replacement action:

```
rmdtext = read_rmd_from_file(filename) # Using your favourite method of text loading
rmdtext = gsub('$USERNAME', 'Jabberwocky', rmdtext)
msg <- envelope() %>% render(rmdstring)
```

**Use rmdmanip**

Shameless self-plug of a package I created: you can use [`rmdmanip`](https://github.com/minimumcosttohumanity/rmdmanip) to manipulate `rmd` parameters.

```
devtools::install_github('minimumcosttohumanity/rmdmanip')
```

The package directly manipulates parameters in an rmd string or file:

```
library(rmdmanip)
# Load file and replace parameters directly in text
rmdstring = read.rmd(filename) %>% 
      put_param('username', 'Jabberwocky') %>% 
      dumps()
msg <- envelope() %>% render(rmdstring)
```

Comment: The author just added that feature. Please see: https://github.com/datawookie/emayili/issues/79

Comment: Thank you very much for all the work you put in here!